# Delete or preserve this question and answers about obscure sorting algorithms?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, polling

In my opinion [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21082/what-is-the-most-obscure-sorting-algorithm-you-know) should be preserved even though it is bad, because it has nice answers worthy of preserving. To pick one example, I personally found idea of *sleep sort* to be rather enlightening in the thinking-outside-of-the-box kind of way.

Comment: The question has been locked for the time being until such time as the community decides whether deletion is acceptable or not.

Comment: To answer your original question -- It's super annoying; I used to hate that.  Being able to see deleted questions is one of the perks I love from being a 10k+ user.

Comment: The [revision history](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/5811/revisions) is enough for people to see past versions of your question, no point in preserving them otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

The Question should stay locked. It is historically significant despite being a polling question.

Despite a few smart-aleck answers, there are some good answers in there.  Most of the suggested algorithms are "non-traditional" which can be useful for learning from when a project has unique requirements.  It's not mentioned in the answer, but [BCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) is an example algorithm that's been intentionally designed to run slower in order to hinder brute force attack.

Comment: I'll volunteer to clean up the smart-aleck answers in that question if we decide to keep it.  Ping me once a decision has been made.

Comment: I wish more leeway were given to questions that are not "correct" but are interesting or provoke interesting responses.  Including whimsical discussions (assuming they have some element of programming interest).  It is not as if Programmers is overflowing with questions.  Allowing a bit more wide-ranging questions would give the site more character, in my opinion.

Comment: Nothing historically significant about the question I'm afraid. +22 question with 1500 views and no inbound links to speak of, this is a meh question at best. Historically significant doesn't mean "old question I personally like", it's a compromise for _truly stellar_ questions that don't belong to the site for whatever reason (more details [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)).

Comment: @dan1111 Hey, you probably don't know that but this site started out exactly as a site where more leeway were given to questions that are not "correct" but are interesting or provoke interesting responses. And it soon turned into a crapfest, and reached a "get serious, or else" point. Fortunately now we have a pretty awesome chat room and a community blog, and we can have all the fun we want there, while keeping the main site as close to its goal (a very high quality canonical resource) as possible.

Comment: @YannisRizos, thanks for the background information.

Answer (score -2):

The Question should be deleted, it is a bad question and we should all feel bad.